# ScatterViewItem IsManipulationEnabled = false Routing Event

Tags: wpf, pixelsense, scatterview

I have a `ScatterViewItem` that I want to host a `UserControl` inside. Now I want to be able to toggle `IsManipulationEnabled` on the `ScatterViewItem` to lock it into place on a `ScatterView`.

When it's locked I want to be able to manipulate the `UserControl` inside (e.g panning, zooming, rotating, etc.).

If I set `IsManipulationEnabled` to false, then it seems to block all events to the `UserControl` because my `ManipulationStarting`, `ManipulationDelta` events hooked to my `UserControl` wont fire.

Is there a way around this problem? I'm just using a simple image as my `UserControl` at the moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ManipulationMode, use CanMove/CanRotate/CanScale

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but my UserControl still can't receive manipulation events.